How do I format text into html automatically in Excel?
I found this answer inhere and it is the question I have, but it does not work for me in Excel
function contentToHtml(text) {
  return text
    .split('\n\n')
    .map(paragraph => `<p>${paragraph}</p>`)
    .join('')
}

This function assumes you hit enter twice when separating paragraphs. It will take in your text and wrap each paragraph in <p> tags.
I get this problem:

Line 29: See line 13, column 24: Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.


Did you use the addin? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts otherwise it likely expects VBA

please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and read How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? and don't forget to read Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question? . Also check out the tour, and help center
